Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 - Getting Not found error
I am trying to create alerts for databases in Azure using Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 command , but approach is working for other resources types like ASP , app services. not working with databases . can some one help me to figure it out.
 $ResourceName = "s0010asq/mfwt1"
$jsonFiles = "sqlalert"
$MetricName = "storage_percent"
$MetricNamespace = "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
$Operator = "GreaterThan"
$Threshold = "90.0"
$TimeAggregation = "Average"
$Actiongroup = "/subscriptions/35324-3245-3245-3425-32453452345/resourceGroups/s00149rgp/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/Infra Sev4"
$WindowSize = "5"
$Frequency = "5"
$Alerts_Severity = "4"
Set-AzContext -Subscription "s00yrjfjhjjhdopdnu74" | Out-Null
$scope = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNames -Name $ResourceName).ResourceId
$alertName = "$ResourceName $MetricName High"

                                Write-Output "`n`n[34;1m**creating $alertName alert with template $($jsonFiles.FullName)**[0m"
                                $condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria  -MetricName $MetricName `
                                    -MetricNamespace $MetricNamespace `
                                    -Operator $Operator `
                                    -Threshold $Threshold `
                                    -TimeAggregation $TimeAggregation `
                                     
                                Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name $alertName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNames `
                                    -TargetResourceId $scope `
                                    -ActionGroupId $Actiongroup `
                                    -WindowSize $WindowSize `
                                    -Frequency $Frequency `
                                    -Condition $condition `
                                    -Severity $Alerts_Severity `
                                    -Description $alertName

Getting error like :


Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:NotFound, Reason phrase: Not Found
At line:24 char:33
+ ...             Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name $alertName -ResourceGroupNa ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleV2Command
> Blockquote


In your code, you have not specified the variable $ResourceGroupNames anywhere, yet you are using it for the -ResourceGroupName parameter.

You said it is only happening with databases.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and get log files which is in the explorer under Management.  There should be a login message when you connect in the PS cmdlet.  There should be a User and Group that is used for the connection.  There may be an error message that explains the issue.


Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 - Getting Not found error

In your code, the $ResourceGroupNames variable is not defined, and the values for Frequency and Alerts_Severity are provided as follows
$WindowSize = [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
$Frequency = [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")

When I use your code, I also get the same error.
Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:NotFound, Reason phrase: Not Found


Here is the updated code to create a alert for SQL Server
$SubscriptionId = "zzzzzznfnfnfnfnffnf"
$ResourceGroupNames = "SQLDB-RG"
$ResourceName= "venkatserverdemo/venkatDB"
$MetricName = "storage_percent"
$Threshold = 90
$TimeAggregation = "Average"
$Operator = "GreaterThan"
$WindowSize = [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
$Frequency = [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("00:05:00")
$Severity = 4
$ActionGroupId = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupNames/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/venkatacg"
$NewAlertName = "venkatserveralert"

Set-AzContext -Subscription $SubscriptionId | Out-Null

$scope = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNames -Name $ResourceName).ResourceId
$Condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName $MetricName `
    -MetricNamespace "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" `
    -Operator $Operator `
    -Threshold $Threshold `
    -TimeAggregation $TimeAggregation

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name $NewAlertName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -TargetResourceId $Scope `
    -ActionGroupId $ActionGroupId `
    -WindowSize $WindowSize `
    -Frequency $Frequency `
    -Condition $Condition `
    -Severity $Severity `
    -Description "Alert for $MetricName with new name"

Output:

The alert was created successfully after running the PowerShell code.


$ResourceName what about this value

In my code i have hardcoded resource group I'd ,if you want you can fetch the I'd from code.

Updated code with $ResourceName.
